# How to add telegram bot to public channel I'm not admin of?

Tags: python, api, bots, telegram, channel

How would I add my telegram bot to a channel in telegram that I'm not administrator of? The channel is one-way communication(the admin sends messages, everyone receives it but can't respond back to the group).

In the change logs of the Bot API in November 21st(https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#november-21-2016) in the second bullet point it says "Your bot can now get updates about posts in channels. Added new fields channel_post and edited_channel_post to Update."

Does this mean my bot can receive messages from channels and act according to them? If so, how would I add the bot to the group without the admin helping me out by adding it?

I have searched here, and other places, for the answer of the question but most seem to say only the admin can add the bot. Is this because the information is out of date, or is it still not possible to add bots? Btw I'm using python.

Thanks for your time and help,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't receive channel message without admin permission. If you can't add bot as admin, there is no way to do that.